# Cobras becoming amphipteres

Tags: evolution, snake

For those who don't know, an amphiptere is basically a dragon with no legs but it has wings. Whether or not these are pseudowings that only allows gliding or bat-like wings that allows flight varies.

(Choosing king cobra for specificity's sake)

What would need to change in a king cobra's current natural environment in order for them to be pressured into adapting their hoods into wings or pseudowings and use them to fly/glide around frequently?

Comment: Firstly: an environment with good height variations.

Comment: Thanks for the nightmare fuel, I regret reading the question... *starts warily looking upwards*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The animals using membranes for gliding use it as a way to quickly get away from heights.

The pressure driving a cobra to do the same would need to:

- push cobras to start frequenting heights, like hunting on/from trees
- push cobras to need a quick descent method, either escape predators or ambush preys

Answer (score 2):

There are "flying" [snakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysopelea) present.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16aGSx9gFO4

They can make their body more flat and use it to glide, but, unlike cobras, they don't have a hood.

I think cobras can learn to flatten their bodies and glide like these ones.

Answer (score 0):

Cobras couldn't become amphipteres because of weight balance. A cobra's hood is so close to the head that it couldn't support the body. The hood also couldn't extend down the body or move back, as there would be no purpose to this adaptation until it reached the right place. Caudal wings might be something that could evolve, but that seems like a bridge too far for this to be an amphiptere